# C# how to make an API with a single entry point (service Class)

Tags: c#, api, design-patterns, visibility

I have to make an API C# that permit VBA(Excel) to use internal ressources(like a DataBase).
I have make a Class Services, that call methods in many others Class (book, music, etcc..). Ressource Classes have CRUD methods to use the internal ressources.

for Exemple i want the VBA devlopper to use API just by calling "My_API.Services.getBookNumber()" (for exemple).

All works properly, but when i try it in Excel, when i write "My_API." i could see all the methods directly without using my Service Class.

How may i resolve that ? i have plenty of Utility Class just for my API usage, and i don't want that the VBA dev use them ^^

ps : i use visual studio 2010 for customer's reason ...

Thanks for your help !

Comment: Did you make all classes and methods `public`? The things you want to hide should be `internal` or `private`, as appropriate.

Comment: in fact when i use internal for the code i want to hide, in the Service Class i have a compile error, for "Inconsistent accessibility : the kind of field My_API.Book.getBookNumber is less accessible than My_API.Services.getBookNumber

Comment: I did say "as appropriate". I obviously cannot see your project but you need to design it with proper encapsulation to achieve your goal.

Comment: It is the kind of mistake induced by using [ClassInterface(ClassInterfaceType.AutoDual)].  Very convenient, but it exposes everything in the class, even the members inherited from System.Object.  Declare an interface instead, adding only the members you want the VBA programmer to see.  And the class that implements it should be ClassInterfaceType.None

Answer (score -1):

> Did you make all classes and methods public? The things you want to
>   hide should be internal or private, as appropriate. – Crowcoder 18
>   hours ago

In fact, all the Class i want to hide must be in "internal" an the controler must call them in private...

I have already test that but my VS2010 still doesn't want to Compile, for no reason, but this morning all is fine and Compile well without changing anything... ^^

Thanks for your help StackOverflow community !